# Refresh Sub-Route in Angular

Tags: angular, router

Let's say I have this route:

```
home/authors/authorId/books-list
```

And I have the year **2022** selected in a dropdown in AuthorComponent(authorId). The year value is stored in a Service.

Then I need to change the year to **2021** and reload the books-list component to get the **2021** data.

I can't refresh the hole route, otherwise I will lose my selected year.

So, I need to force reload only the last part of the route, whenever I change the selected year in the dropdown.

There is a way I can force the component "books-list" only, to reload its data?

What would be the recommendation?

**PS.: I can't make big changes in this logic.**

Comment: So... How are you doing it right now? What does the logic look like? This could be as simple as onchange event from dropdown and resubscribe, or perhaps just using behaviour subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up forcing a navigation. This way I could refresh the data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ChangeDetectorRef for the purpose of reloading the component.

First

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
```

and add ChangeDetectionStrategy in the component decorator:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-your',
  templateUrl: './your.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./your.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
```

Then inject ChangeDetectorRef in your component contrustor:

```
contructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef)
```

Finally, add the function call in your callback when you change the date:

```
this.cdRef.detectChanges();
```